# K-NET Paymanet Gateway Integration with OpenCart

Tags: php, payment-gateway, opencart

I want to integrate KNET Payment gateway into my OpenCart 1.5.3.1 Website but i am unable to find any help regarding this. Can anyone guide me or help me out to sort out my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to basically copy an existing payment gateway from opencart, and work from there passing any info the documentation for your payment gateway requests. I'd recommend you use the PayPal Pro for most gateways, but it really depends what type of payment gateway it is (iframe, redirect to processor etc)